# Issue with uitableview cell background

Tags: uitableview, ios7

Ok, this is broken as of iOS 7 Beta 6.

On startup, I changed the background of the table view to an image (it does the same thing if I set it to a color) and the table cells are white...

When I select a cell, go to the next view, and then go back to this view... the cells are the same as the view background (except the cell I selected)...

This is where I set the background...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

pacListTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dotted-pattern.png"]];
pacListTableView.backgroundView = nil;

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

}

Any ideas?  It works fine on iOS and below.

Comment: U mean the cell was on selected state, when coming back to this view?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting background color of your table view cell to clear color. Until IOS 7 default background was clear color. But with IOS 7 it has changed to  White color. So you have to manually set it to clear color.

Answer (score 1):

With iOS7 the default backgroundColor of a cell is white instead of clearColor. You have to explicitly set the desired backgroundColor on the cell's contentView (not on the cell itself).

So in your case you'd have to insert

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

inside

```
 - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```